# How to associate Unity Dash's buttons to the preferred applications?

Tags: 10.10, unity

Unity Dash shows some big buttons by hitting the Ubuntu logo: Internet, Mail, Games, Music. I'm currently using different programs than the original ones included in Ubuntu, but these buttons have become useless, not opening any application. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: aren't those buttons categories?

Comment: They're not. I was they used to launch Evolution, Firefox, Rhythmbox but after I replaced these apps with others, the buttons became of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Unity in 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

Your preferred applications dictate which apps do what in the dash.

Comment: Not in Maverick I'm afraid.

Comment: ah, sorry about that, I missed the 10.10 tag