# How can I start videos/music in my preferred player and not the default one using Dash?

Tags: 12.04, default-programs

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and VLC is configurated as my standard video player, Clementine for audio. Works fine when I start a video or audio in Nautilus.

But whenever I start a video from Dash it's opened with the default Ubuntu video player, Totem. For music, Rhythmbox is started.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

(I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29142/how-to-associate-unity-dashs-buttons-to-the-preferred-applications) but since it is about 10.10 maybe it's out-dated)

EDIT: Ok, I changed it now myself. I had to use Ubuntu Tweak to set all the file type endings. Is there a way to do it without using Ubuntu Tweak? Setting the default applications in the System Settings wasn't enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on any video file and select "Properties".

Click on "Open With" tab of "Properties dialog box"

Select "VLC media player" and click on "Set as default"

[image]

Do the same for audio files and set "Clementine" as your default player.